# Autocomplete form field with JQuery from external JSON not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

The first step of my complex form is to autocomplete a field with some external data located in a json. I tried and followed multiple examples and documentation but I am unable to make it work...

For this external json:

```
[
  {
    "Nombre": "Adoración Pérez",
    "DNI": "23123",
    "Telefono": ""
  },
  {
    "Nombre": "Adriana Suárez",
    "DNI": "345345435",
    "Telefono": ""
  },
  {
    "Nombre": "Agueda Delmiro",
    "DNI": "6u56u6tJ",
    "Telefono": 12312434
  },
  {
    "Nombre": "Aida Aguilera",
    "DNI": "46456456A",
    "Telefono": 13123213
  },
  {
    "Nombre": "Aladino Valdés",
    "DNI": "67867845eG",
    "Telefono": ""
  },
  {
    "Nombre": "Alberto Martinez",
    "DNI": "235436456",
    "Telefono": ""
  }
]
```

This is my full JS:

```
$(function() {

    var entries = []

    $.getJSON('pacientes.json', function(json) {
        for (var key in json) {
            if (json.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                var item = json[key];
                entries.push(item);
            }
        }

        console.log(entries)

        $("#species").autocomplete({
            minLength: 0,
            source: entries,
            focus: function(event, ui) {
                $("#species").val(ui.item.Nombre);
                return false;
            },
            select: function(event, ui) {
                $("#species").val(ui.item.Nombre);
                $( "#identifiant" ).val( ui.item.DNI );

                return false;
            }
        })
    });


});
```

This is my  full HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>HTML Forms</h2>

<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="species">Species: </label>
  <input id="species">
  <label for="identifiant">Identifiant: </label>
  <input id="identifiant" style="width: 6em;">
</form> 

<p>If you click the "Submit" button, the form-data will be sent to a page called "/action_page.php".</p>

<script src="js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="js/parse_data.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

I tried several different options but cannot autocomplete data. Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you used tools to determine if the issue is the http request or the autocomplete api? Are there errors in the browser console? Please share if there are any errors or not. If there are errors, please paste the text from the error and include code related to the stack trace.

Comment: No errors shown in the console ...

Comment: Your entries do not match the proper format. It must contain an array of objects with label and value properties: `[ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]`

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example.

```js
$(function() {
  // Load entries once
  var entries = [];
  $.getJSON('pacientes.json', function(json) {
    $.each(function(key, val) {
      if (json.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        entries.push(json);
      }
    });

    // Initialize Autocomplete
    $("#species").autocomplete({
      minLength: 0,
      source: function(req, resp) {
        var myData = [];
        $.each(entries, function(key, val) {
          if (val.Nombre.indexOf(req.term) == 0) {
            myData.push({
              label: val.Nombre,
              value: val.DNI,
              Nombre: val.Nombre,
              DNI: val.DNI,
              Telefono: val.Telefono
            });
          }
          console.log(myData);
          resp(myData);
        });
      },
      focus: function(event, ui) {
        $("#species").val(ui.item.Nombre);
        return false;
      },
      select: function(event, ui) {
        $("#species").val(ui.item.Nombre);
        $("#identifiant").val(ui.item.DNI);
        return false;
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<h2>HTML Forms</h2>

<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="species">Species: </label>
  <input id="species" type="text" />
  <label for="identifiant">Identifiant: </label>
  <input id="identifiant" type="text" style="width: 6em;" />
</form>

<p>If you click the "Submit" button, the form-data will be sent to a page called "/action_page.php".</p>

<script src="js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="js/parse_data.js"></script>
```

This will allow you to configure custom data and still format the Array as needed.

Reference: https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source

You can also make use of `$.ui.autocomplete.filter()`.

```
var myData = [];
$.each(entries, function(key, val) {
  myData.push({
    label: val.Nombre,
    value: val.DNI,
    Nombre: val.Nombre,
    DNI: val.DNI,
    Telefono: val.Telefono
  });
  console.log(myData);
  resp($.ui.autocomplete.filter(myData, req.term));
});
```